# Vimscript: Cannot import modules on sys.path

Tags: python, vim, module

I am trying to import a module inside a vimscript plugin. I have verified the path is correct and there exists a `__init__.py` in the same dir. Similar code works just fine when used in other python scripts.

```
let s:current_dir = expand("<sfile>:p:h")
python << EOP
import sys
import vim

current_dir = vim.eval("s:current_dir")
libs_path = "{}/../python/src/main/python/libs".format(current_dir)

sys.path.insert(0, libs_path)
import libs
EOP
```

The errr `ImportError: No module named libs`

Comment: Are you sure that `libs` itself should be on the end of that directory path?  i.e. is the actual module name `../python/src/main/python/libs/libs.py`?

Comment: The directory is named `libs`. And tried using just "..../main/python/" with same result. The end result should be that I can use something like `from libs import myutils`

Comment: Have you tried printing `libs_path` to be sure it contains the correct value?  Maybe `vim.eval()` is returning something unexpected.

Comment: Verified that libs_path is correct. Also, used `os.path.exists(libs_path)` to verify that python could see the dir.

Comment: Just to be very clear: there actually exists a file `../python/src/main/python/libs/libs/__init__.py`?

Comment: No its at `../python/src/main/python/libs/__init__.py`. only one "libs" in the path.

Comment: Then `libs` should not be at the end of the path.  But you said you tried that, so I don't know what the issue is.  Have you successfully done similar things using vim before?

Comment: Well crap... So tried it again without the "libs" and it worked. Swore I tried that. @JohnGordon, if you put your last comment in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libs` should not be at the end of the path.